# Date not correct

Tags: java

I want to display months with the names. So i'm using JODA.jar

This is my code :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date1 = "2013-21-01 14:00:00";
    String date2 = "2013-01-01 14:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date11, date22;
    try {
        date11 = sdf.parse(date1);
        System.out.println("Date : " +date11);
        date22 = sdf.parse(date2);
        System.out.println("Date : " +date22);

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date11);
    String monthName1 = dt1.monthOfYear().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH); 
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(date22);
    String monthName2 = dt2.monthOfYear().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH); 

    System.out.println("String1 : " +monthName1+" "+dt1.getYear());
    System.out.println("String2 : " +monthName2+" "+dt2.getYear());
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
    }
```

In the first date, I put 21 like month, this is not possible. But I have this in the Console :

```
  Date : Mon Sep 01 14:00:00 GMT+01:00 2014
  Date : Tue Jan 01 14:00:00 GMT+01:00 2013
  String1 : September 2014
  String2 : January 2013
```

How it can be like this ? Normally it shouldn't show the first date, just the right date, right ?

Comment: `21 - 12 = 9 = September`. So it probably overflows to next year.

Comment: What sould I do to avoid this please ?

Comment: Your date appears to be yyyy-dd-MM, not yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's currently rolling over to the next year.

```
21 - 12 = 9 = September
```

So that it doesn't rollover, just make it [non-lenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

```
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

Comment: @humoule That's what is expected. `20` is not an acceptable or valid month value when leniency is `false`.

Comment: Exactly ! what should I do to avoid this error please ? When the date is false, normally it show anything.

Comment: @Humoule It's an exception, you have to handle it. The date isn't false, it's just not in the proper format. That is the meaning of `ParseException`.

Comment: @Humoule You are asking specifically for this error, by setting lenient. You just need to ensure that you catch and handle it.

Comment: @Humoule If you want to avoid it, make it impossible to provide months greater than 12.

Answer (score 1):

Java date parsing is referred to as `lenient` - it allows parsing of dates that aren't technically valid, and works out what the user may have been referring to.

In this particular case, it's seen month 21 of 2013, assumed that the user was being lazy in incrementing months, and taken it to mean month 9 of 2014 - September.

More information on leniency can be found [in the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29).

Comment: Perfect. But what should I do to avoid this error please ? When the date is false, normally it show anything.

Comment: @Humoule As another answer has said, use `setLenient()` - it's in the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

21 is 12+9 so by entering this you added 1 year to the date you wanted to set actually.